# Android Studio Stop Button not Stopping

Tags: android, android-studio

This has to be a dumb question, but in Android Studio 0.3.2 I'm attempting to stop my app at a particular spot so I can test a particular automatic resume feature the next time I restart the app (to imitate a failure). However, when I hit the stop button in the debugger, it just disconnects and the app keeps on running. Am I misunderstanding what the stop button does? Is there any way to legitimately kill the app from the debugger like you can for iOS apps in XCode?

Comment: I am not sure about Android Studio but in eclipse you can do this so there is always an alternative to test it in

Comment: I confirm that strange behaviour :)

Answer (score 4):

The stop button simply disconnects the debugger from your device.

To accomplish what you are trying to test you will have to press the home button which will go through the activity life cycle until onStop(). When you open your app again it will onStart() then onResume().

If you need more assistance just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`Android Studio` and `Android` uses different approach than `Xcode` and `iOS`

Android Studio stops debugger instead of application that is why you should manage application/activity/fragment lifecycle on OS level. For example you can open another app or press home button or navigate to another screen